# Image size does not change when I configured as responsive design

Tags: css, image, responsive

**What I want to do**

I created the homepage that has some images. I would like to show up them by the responsive design. However, all image files' size are not changed when I show on the iPhone.
There are 3 types img files on HP.
The images are ...

1. files shows up by changing the 3 pics by each 2 seconds at the same place.
2. normal img files.
3. As the gallery, that the img file change to show up by clicking the thumbnail button.

All of them are not changed img size when responsive.

```js
//const img = ["hoge.png", "foo.png", "bar.jpg"];
const img = ["https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w1024-h683-n-l50-sg-rj", "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/fl-GT6w3Ls6RT4vYnbkuYUyLY3lZJH8VtZ7xzxiym9YYaoVRCnZehdz6Icd0oAf6i3H9-O5cCNs6eunlxWr_Csstgsb98DdzNdLFBOlhw9NUfHdyuQjI=w768-h1024-n-l50-sg-rj", "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9pPCK70Rw0k3wethMHb1qMaIB0VjeWLy57vYgSzKbF7oJuvO2nA0Nakk-95cvibWUDcEhYkfCKvdPKT03tXZd4M5jdhIEibLO9qw-XE=w1024-h683-n-l50-sg-rj"];

let count = -1;

const hoge = () => {
  count++;
  // カウントが最大になれば初期値に戻す
  if (count == img.length) count = 0;
  //画像選択
  pic.src = img[count];
  //1秒ごとに実行    
  setTimeout(() => {
    hoge();
  }, 2000);
}

window.onload = () => {

  hoge();

}




//アルバムデータの作成
let album = [{
    src: 'img/1.png',
    msg: 'さまざまな形のパスタと自然の恵みを生かしたイタリアン'
  },
  {
    src: 'img/2.png',
    msg: 'パスタだけでなく軽食やスイーツも'
  },
  {
    src: 'img/3.png',
    msg: '肉料理やピザもイタリアン料理を彩ります'
  },
  {
    src: 'img/4.png',
    msg: '豊富な種類のピザ'
  },
  {
    src: 'img/5.png',
    msg: 'チーズが主役だったり生ハムが主役だったり、ピザの種類は豊富です'
  }
];

//最初のデータを表示しておく
let mainImage = document.createElement('img');
mainImage.setAttribute('src', album[0].src);
mainImage.setAttribute('alt', album[0].msg);

let mainMsg = document.createElement('p');
mainMsg.innerText = mainImage.alt;

let mainFlame = document.querySelector('#gallery .main');
mainFlame.insertBefore(mainImage, null);
mainFlame.insertBefore(mainMsg, null);

//サムネイル写真の表示
let thumbFlame = document.querySelector('#gallery .thumb');
for (let i = 0; i < album.length; i++) {
  let thumbImage = document.createElement('img');
  thumbImage.setAttribute('src', album[i].src);
  thumbImage.setAttribute('alt', album[i].msg);
  thumbFlame.insertBefore(thumbImage, null);
}

//クリックした画像をメインにする
thumbFlame.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.src) {
    mainImage.src = event.target.src;
    mainMsg.innerText = event.target.alt;
  }
});
```

```css
.under {
  border-bottom: dotted 2px #87cdfa
}

.fixed {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

img.calbo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

img.pepe {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#gallery {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 40px;
  width: 700px;
}

#gallery .main img {
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0;
}

#gallery .main p {
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#gallery .thumb img {
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  test {
    float: none;
  }
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <font color="#EEEEEE">レシピ ～ カルボナーラとペペロンチーノ</h1>
<br>
<hr width="700" align="left">
<!--- html ----->
<img id="pic" src="hoge.png" width="600" height=auto class="top">
<p>
  <table>

    <tr>
      <th class="fixed"><img src="calbo150.png" class="calbo"></th>
      <td style="background-color:#476072">
        ちょっとしたひと工夫で普通の手作り<br> カルボからお店風本格カルボに。
        <br> 失敗もしない簡単レシピ
        <br><br>
        <a href="calbo.html" class="calbo" style="background-color:#476072">カルボナーラのレシピ</a>

      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th class="fixed"><img src="pepe.jpg" class="pepe"></th>
      <td style="background-color:#476072">
        簡単だけど難しいペペロンチーノ。<br> 材料と水分調整がうまくいけば本格的な
        <br> ペペロンチーノに仕上がります。
        <br><br>
        <a href="pepe.html" class="pepe" style="background-color:#476072">ペペロンチーノのレシピ</a>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</p>
<!-- JavaScript -->
<div id="gallery">
  <div class="main">
  </div>
  <div class="thumb">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have quiet a few `px` units in your css, perhaps you should start there.

Comment: I changed the px from the below to below but the behavior was not changed.
　　From ; ＠media screen and (max-width: 480px)
        To;      ＠media screen and (max-width: 800px)

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what the problem is? When I tried your snippet on an iPhone emulator the images went to width 100% OK. Some other things like the hr aren't responsive so you need to look at those but I couldn't see what the problem with the imgs was - though setting initial attribute width=600 is probably not needed. Is there a reason you don't want the imgs to go above 600px width?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the HTML is thoroughly invalid and uses obsolete elements.

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn’t paste the full HTML here, I used the double byte double quotation in the settings of the Viewport line. After I modified to single byte one, it started to work.